# Not able to call a function for cronjob in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a cron job by creating a function for it.This function is created in functions.php in my theme folder in Wordpress. I have set logs in the function. The code for it goes as follows:-

```
add_action('my_daily_event','send_notification_daily');
function my_activation() {
        if ( !wp_next_scheduled('my_daily_event' ) ) {
                wp_schedule_event( current_time( 'timestamp' ), 'daily', 'my_daily_event');
        }
}
add_action('wp', 'my_activation');
function send_notification_daily(){
//send some notification daily
error_log("is this working");
}
```

The error_log does not show up with the set log "is it working". That means the function is not working. But why? I am not able to understand this.

I am scratching my head from last 2 days on this. But i am unable to figure out a solution for it. Please somebody help me making this function work.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

If it is working normally without cron job and not with cron job, make sure all include paths are absolute. Relative path does not work fine with cron job

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir. But,Which path are you talking about sir. I haven't included any i think. And i haven't checked it for other functions but this function is created in functions.php where other functions are working  so can you tell me y is it not reaching till this function